# Formatting date column while generating excel using closedxml when columns are dynamic

Tags: closedxml

While generating excel from datatable using closedxml how to format date columns when columns are dynamic? that is datatable may not consist date column or if consist then can be on any index?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: `ClosedXML` should automatically detect the datatype from the `DataTable`'s columns. But as Toby says, you should formulate your question much better if you expect help.